# There is an error although I followed documentation

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import *

def wider():
    global photo,lbpic
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = Image.open(pic)
    width,height = adj.size
    new_pic = adj.resize((width*2,height))
    new_pic.save('Wider'+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = new_pic
    lbpic.image = new_pic

def taller():
    global photo,lbpic
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = Image.open(pic)
    width,height = adj.size
    new_pic = adj.resize((width,height*2))
    new_pic.save('Taller'+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = new_pic
    lbpic.image = new_pic

def rotateangle():
    global photo,lbpic,var
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = Image.open(pic)
    angle = var.get()
    result = adj.rotate(angle)
    result.save('rotated'+angle+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = result
    lbpic.image = result

def rotate():
    global photo,lbpic
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(90)
    rb1 = Radiobutton(win,text='90',variable=var,value=90,command=rotateangle)
    rb1.place(x=100,y=110)
    rb2 = Radiobutton(win,text='180',variable=var,value=180,command=rotateangle)
    rb2.place(x=100,y=140)
    rb3 = Radiobutton(win,text='270',variable=var,value=270,command=rotateangle)
    rb3.place(x=100,y=170)
    
    
win = Tk()
win.title('Photo adjust')
win.geometry('400x400')

lb = Label(win,text='Select a photo')
lb.place(x=100,y=20)

photo = StringVar()
en = Entry(win,textvariable=photo,width=30)
en.place(x=100,y=50)

btn = Button(win,text='Wider',command=wider)
btn.place(x=100,y=80)

btn2 = Button(win,text='Taller',command=taller)
btn2.place(x=150,y=80)

btnrotate = Button(win,text='Rotate',command=rotate)
btnrotate.place(x=200,y=80)

lbpic = Label(win,image='')
lbpic.place(x=150,y=200)

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Python/Python Projects Fun/photo_shop.py", line 7, in wider
    adj = Image.open(pic)
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

For this program, I would like to select a picture to change different effects within the buttons. However I am not able to open image by using `Image.open(pic)` but I have already checked thoroughly the documentation that Image module has `open` method. I followed the documentation but I do not understand where is the problem? Or the version problem?

Comment: You are using `tkinter.Image` instead of `PIL.Image` becuse `from tkinter import *` override `from PIL import Image`.  Swap the two import statements.  Also you need `PhotoImage` instance instead of `Image` to be assigned to widget.

Comment: your problem shows why `import *` is not preferred. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on Windows::

## solution 1

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = tk.Tk()

myImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('test.png'))  # your image here

# you can do anything with that image object now.
# You can get all the common image formats (i used a png image)
# The PhotoImage object may not have attributes like PIL.Image 
# SO IN THAT CASE CHECK MY SECOND SOLUTION BELOW
#

tk.Label(root, image=myImage).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

## Reason :

according to Your `import` statements (you have used `global imports` - also called `wildcard imports`), The Image object from `tkinter` library overrides `Image` object you imported from `PIL`.
Which makes it hard for the `interpreter` to know if you have really used `PIL.Image` or `tkinter.Image`.

*** That's why it is recommended to use import statements like this***

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as Immmage # or whatever name you prefer
import tkinter.messagebox as msgb
from pyautogui import size
```

## Solution 2 (For your needs)

You own code may even work if you change your `import style`.

```
from PIL import Image as someThingElse  # your choice again
from tkinter import *   # again global import not recommended but only if you need so

def wider():
    global photo,lbpic
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = someThingElse.open(pic)
    width,height = adj.size
    new_pic = adj.resize((width*2,height))
    new_pic.save('Wider'+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = new_pic
    lbpic.image = new_pic

def taller():
    global photo,lbpic
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = someThingElse.open(pic)
    width,height = adj.size
    new_pic = adj.resize((width,height*2))
    new_pic.save('Taller'+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = new_pic
    lbpic.image = new_pic

def rotateangle():
    global photo,lbpic,var
    pic = photo.get()
    adj = someThingElse.open(pic)
    angle = var.get()
    result = adj.rotate(angle)
    result.save('rotated'+angle+pic)
    lbpic['image'] = result
    lbpic.image = result

def rotate():
    global photo,lbpic
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(90)
    rb1 = Radiobutton(win,text='90',variable=var,value=90,command=rotateangle)
    rb1.place(x=100,y=110)
    rb2 = Radiobutton(win,text='180',variable=var,value=180,command=rotateangle)
    rb2.place(x=100,y=140)
    rb3 = Radiobutton(win,text='270',variable=var,value=270,command=rotateangle)
    rb3.place(x=100,y=170)
    
    
win = Tk()
win.title('Photo adjust')
win.geometry('400x400')

lb = Label(win,text='Select a photo')
lb.place(x=100,y=20)

photo = StringVar()
en = Entry(win,textvariable=photo,width=30)
en.place(x=100,y=50)

btn = Button(win,text='Wider',command=wider)
btn.place(x=100,y=80)

btn2 = Button(win,text='Taller',command=taller)
btn2.place(x=150,y=80)

btnrotate = Button(win,text='Rotate',command=rotate)
btnrotate.place(x=200,y=80)

lbpic = Label(win,image='')
lbpic.place(x=150,y=200)
```

Comment: How about if I want to get the image file to adjust into different effects like resize, rotating and show as in label?

Comment: @Dom807 Yes you can, The above code actually fits the image inside a label (second last line in the code).  You can fit it on a Button as well. Also see my edits above to know more.

Comment: I can do it now. Thanks very much

Comment: Edited my answer again for specifically your needs (with your code). Also please accept the answer only if it helped so as to close the question :) Good Luck